# SQL query many-to-many ralationship problem

Tags: sql, t-sql, many-to-many

I am learning SQL and I have problem with building a query and I can't find any material to solve this. I will explain it on Album/Tracks database.

So here is

[image: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/194/diagramtt.png/]

and that what I want to do:

[image: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/803/selectwithwhere.png/]

I am sure answer is obvious but it really gives me a headache.

Mariusz

---

(EDIT by ypercube):

My wild guess is that OP wants to show all `Albums` and `Tracks` for those `Albums` that **no** `Trackname` with `'UnwantedTrackName'` exists.

Comment: what further filtering conditions do you want?

Comment: Which TrackName exactly you want in the result?

Comment: I want all albums without track with name "Sometrack1" it means in this situation only album3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
select
 a.*
from Album as a
where a.Album_Id not in 
(
    select
     at.Album_Id
    from AlbumTrack as at
        join Track as t
        on t.Track_Id = at.Track_Id
    where t.TrackName ='SomeTrack1'
)
```

Comment: Thx sir =] it is working but instead of 'Sometrack%' i have to wrtie 'Sometrack1' ofcource. Now I have to implement that in NHibernate ^^ so fingers croseed guys.

Comment: You don't need `DISTINCT` in a `[NOT] IN` operation - if the optimizer is feeling dense, it could actually slow the query down.

Answer (score 1):

Would be a lot easier for us if you included your code and results in your question, rather than forcing us to re-type it.

You want all Albums and Tracks, for all Albums which don't include one particular track:

```
select
    a.AlbumName,t.TrackName
from
    Album a
       inner join
    AlbumTrack at
       on
          a.ID = at.AlbumID
       inner join
    Track t
       on
          at.TrackID = t.ID
       left join
    AlbumTrack at_anti
       inner join
    Track t_anti
       on
           at_anti.TrackID = t_anti.TrackID and
           t_anti.TrackName = 'Unwanted Track'
       on
           at.AlbumID = at_anti.AlbumID
where
    at_anti.TrackID is null
```

Comment: It shows me full result like in first picture. But thank you for trying to help me.

Comment: @Mariusz - did you rename 'Unwanted Track' to 'Sometrack1'?

Answer (score 0):

It's not quite clear what you are asking, but will "INNER JOIN" give you what you want?

Answer (score 0):

Try INNER JOINing the tracks table. If that doesn't work, push the WHERE condition into the ON clause - like

```
track AS t ON (t.id = at.TrackID AND t.TrackName != 'UnwantedTrackName')
```

Comment: It is good for that situation but imagine if I will have 1000 albums =]

Comment: I have rewritten the response - please see if the solutions work for you